# Rewrite to another TLD for all subdomains

Tags: regex, http, nginx, url-rewriting

I want to achieve the following rewrite with nginx:

```
example.com -> example.io
*.example.com -> *.example.io
```

So anything that is related to `example.com` should be redirected to `example.io`, while preserving the subdomain if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a simple server block to listen on example.com and redirect to example.io

```
http {

map $server_name $redirect_to {
   default example.io;
   "~*^(.*)\.example.com$"  $1.example.io;
}

server {

listen 80;

listen 443 ssl;
server_name example.com *.example.com;
ssl_certificate ...;
ssl_certificate_key ....;

return 302 $scheme://$redirect_to$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I don't think, that the tilde in line 5 should be there.